# How to change text color dynamically matching user input string

Tags: java, android, text, colors

I started android apps development today and wanted to make a small app that takes some text as input (a color) and returns the text input with the color chosen by the user.

I started by creating a colors.xml in this fashion:

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
...
```

Then I created an EditText in the main activity, and an activity for displaying the colored text, which included in the onCreate:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(70);
textView.setText(message);
```

Which worked fine, but I could not manage a way to retreive the text string and match it with the color in colors.xml. I was thinking something on the lines of parameter substitution in BASH, like:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.XXXXXX));
```

But I do not know what to put instead of "XXXXXX", as putting "message" would not work, but putting the direct color name (e.g. red) works, but only for one color.

I am trying to avoid case statements, also because I would like to make it as general as possible for many colors. Can anyone suggest if this is possible, in this way or in another way. I am sorry if this is trivial, but I do not have much confidence with Java.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation of the `Color` class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

Basically, if you want to set the color from the `message` string, you could do:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(message));
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. The *colors.xml* file isn't needed for this.
Read the documentation of the `Color` class and don't forget to use a *try-catch* for the `IllegalArgumentException` that the `parseColor()` method can throw.

Answer (score 0):

this R.color.XXXXXX is a integer. You need to grab the whole parameter instead of just XXX, basically you can store the colors in a static integer variables and then use them depending on your condition. Hope this helps.